# How can I add some Jar plugin to the run-time class-path in Netbeans when clicking run file on the Applet from within the NetBeans enviorment?

Tags: java, netbeans, applet, netbeans-6.9

As you see from the above subject
How can I add some Jar plugin to the run-time class-path in Netbeans which will be launched upon clicking "run file" on the Applet class file, from within the NetBeans environment?

I mean that the result will be like running the following HTML code with my jar file:

```
<HTML> 
<BODY> 
<APPLET 
    archive="MyGame.jar,mp3plugin.jar" 
    code="GUI.JPanelGameApplet" 
    width=800 
    height=580>
</APPLET> 
</P> 
</BODY> 
</HTML>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your Projects view right click on Libraries, and then click on Add Jar/Folder...

Comment: where should I add it?
on compile , processor or run tab ?